# Excel VBA - Insert time in another column when a column containing RTD updates values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has RTD (real time data) and I would like to create a macro that
when the values of column “B” with 1000 cells with RTD update their values, automatically record in the corresponding cells next to these values (column “A”) the hour, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.
And if any cell in column “B” is blank, leave the time cell blank.

I managed to make a macro, but it only works for a specific cell, I need the macro to work for a column with 1000 cells.

[Table layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cncoa.png)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("B2").Value = "" Then
        Range("A2").Value = ""
    Else
        Static oldval
        If Range("B2").Value <> oldval Then
            oldval = Range("B2").Value
            Range("A2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text([now()] - tStart, "h:mm:ss.000")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How column RTD gets updated?